# Add legend in ggplot - point/line and segment

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a legend to a ggplot. Unfortunately I can't make the entries in the legend to belong to the same category. Either the entries are not on top of each other or the colors does not match. I would like to have it as shown on the attached picture.

[image]

My code is:

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(
                   c(0, 0.222, 0.369, 0.599, 0.703, 0.725, 0.755, 0.779, 0.803, 1), 
                   c(1, 0.794, 0.594, 0.399, 0.302, 0.272, 0.256, 0.223, 0.207, 0), 
                   c(155.7, 93.2, 93.2, 91.7, 89.7, 89, 89.6, 89.7, 89.3, 98.7),
                   c(156.2, 143.3, 138.2, 115.7, 91.3, 92.5, 91.9, 94.3, 95, 100.3)
                  )

colnames(data) <- c('massA', 'massB', 'TA', 'TE')

x <- data$massB/(data$massA + data$massB)
y1 <- data$TA
y2 <- data$TE

eutecticline <- mean(data$TA[2:(length(data$TA)-1)])

df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)

ggplot(data=df) +
geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2), color = 'red') +
geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2), color = 'red') +
geom_segment(x=0, xend=1, y=eutecticline, yend=eutecticline, color='blue', linetype = 'dashed') +
ylab("Temperature") +
xlab("Mass percent in B") +
theme_bw()
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Where is `y1,y2` in you sample data! Your code can not be reproduced!

Comment: Sry, I have edited the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach which is close to what you want. The key is moving the color and linetype elements inside `aes()` in order to create the legend. After that you can format with `scale_*_()` and customize the legend with `guides()`. Here the code with two options for you:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2, color = 'TE')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2,  color = 'TE',linetype = 'TE')) +
  geom_segment(x=0, xend=1, y=eutecticline,
               yend=eutecticline,
               aes(color='TA', linetype = 'TA')) +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  xlab("Mass percent in B") +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed','solid'))+
  labs(color='Variable',linetype='Variable')
```

Output:

[image]

If more customization is needed:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2, color = 'TE')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2,  color = 'TE',linetype = 'TE')) +
  geom_segment(x=0, xend=1, y=eutecticline,
               yend=eutecticline,
               aes(color='TA', linetype = 'TA')) +
  ylab("Temperature") +
  xlab("Mass percent in B") +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red'))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed','solid'))+
  labs(color='Variable',linetype='Variable')+
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(NA,16))))
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit later than Duck, but here is my solution. Which is close to Ducks one.

Grettings

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red"),labels=c("TA","TE")) +
  geom_point(aes(x=x, y=y2, color = 'red')) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2, color = 'red')) +
  geom_segment(x=0, xend=1, y=eutecticline, yend=eutecticline, linetype = 'dashed',aes(col="blue")) +
  labs(x="Mass percent in B",y="Temperature",color="Legend") +
  theme_bw()
```